# How can I make the client ignore a response UDP in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client-server

I'm fairly new to coding. I'm writing a simple client-server program in C that sends a ping over UDP socket.

My problem is that I need my client side to ignore a response after (2 secs for ex), and just send another ping instead, and count the first one as lost.

```c
void waitReply(ping_t * pet, ssize_t * n_data_recv,  clock_t * init_send){

    size_t total_data_rcv = 0;
    clock_t aux_intv;
   
    while( total_data_rcv  < (strlen(REPLY)) ){
        *(n_data_recv) = recvfrom(pet->socket,pet->buffer,BUFFER_SIZE -1 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)0,(int *)0);
       
        if(*(n_data_recv) < 0){
            printf("Error: cannot recv data\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        total_data_rcv += *(n_data_recv);
        pet->buffer[*n_data_recv] = '\0';
        pet->data_recv += *(n_data_recv);

        if(IntervalTimer(&aux_intv,init_send) > (0.9*INTERVAL_REQUEST)){            
            pet->pings_lost++;
            break;
        }
    }

    fnl = clock() - beg;
    fnl= fnl / 1000;

    if(total_data_rcv  == (strlen(REPLY))){
        pet->pings_rcv++;
        printf("%d: Sent... RTT= %f ms\n",  pet->pings_rcv,fnl);
        
        if(fnl < min)
            min = fnl;
        if (fnl > max)
            max = fnl;       
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can't actually tell the OS to ignore the response per se. What you can do is to timeout if the response is not received after a certain amount of time. But be aware that you would still need to receive and handle a response that comes in after the timeout (you can "ignore" it at that point by just doing nothing with that late response). If it is indeed a timeout you want then please update your question and search using "recv timeout" keywords.

Comment: The OS has no way of knowing which responses are "late"; it will tell you about each response that comes in., You will need to filter out late replies yourself, perhaps by tagging each ping request in a way that will be echoed back by the remote, so that you can tell which replies belong to requests that happened more than two seconds ago.